# Github api v3 commit blob

Tags: git, github

I am trying to commit to github through the api. I am able to add a blob but then while trying to then add a tree using the blob as a path I get a Server Error.

I am sending the following json string:

```
{
    "tree":
    {
        "type":"blob",
        "path":"30387681ee9e06c8abd1a76536f3db000ed45a11",
        "sha":"30387681ee9e06c8abd1a76536f3db000ed45a11",
        "mode":100644
    }
}
```

The docs state that the path should be the sha of the blob added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path should not be the SHA-1 of the blob added, it should be relative path of that blob in the repository.

The [docs](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#create-a-tree) shows the following tree creation example input:

```
{
  "tree": [
    {
      "path": "file.rb",
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "sha": "44b4fc6d56897b048c772eb4087f854f46256132"
    }
  ]
}
```